# Trying to tests parts of a string from a list

Tags: python, string

I have a block like this:

```
example of list:
pommes : 54
bananes : 18 : 99
orange
```

Ìt's testing if the left string and the right string are separated by **:** and the type of the right string is **int**.

I'm trying to get that extra ": 99" to be caught as an error. Also, the fact that if **my :** is absent. If there any way to add and associate it to gauche2[2].

```
for i in message:
    parts = i.split(":")
    gauche = parts[0].strip()
    droite = parts[1]
    try:
        droite = int(droite)
        if not gauche.isalpha():
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
    except ValueError:
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, currently it's not valid python. `if len(parts) == 3:` can check if you have 3 parts. What is `gauche2`?

Comment: gauche[2] would be a new argument that would have parts[2] assigned? sry i fixed the indentation

Comment: What does the data need to look like when you're done going through the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **split()** and **len**:

```
data = """
exemple of list:
pommes : 54
bananes : 18 : 99
orange 
"""

for line in data.splitlines():
    if len(line.split(':')) > 2:
        raise ValueError(line, '<< bad line')
```

For your example:

```
for i in message:
    parts = i.split(":")
    if len(parts) > 2:
        raise ValueError(i, '<< bad line')
```

Comment: Nice, instead of raising the error you could also assign another variable under that if statement for parts[2].

Comment: na i  need to print a message and then sys.exit() also can you look at my other question... because of the orange ligne that is alone i get this error droite = parts[1] IndexError: list index out of range